# How to test state update in function component? (state in parent component, update logic in child)

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have functions called **changeStatus** and **deleteItem** in component **TodoItem.js**

When a button (with the className of **btn-info**) is clicked, the **changeStatus** function is called and it changes the todo item's "complete" state to opposite (default is false, so it should turn to true).

When a button (with the className of **btn-danger**) is clicked, the **deleteItem** function is called and it removes the item from the todos array.

---

The state for todo item is in App.js from where the **todos** array and **setTodos** function are passed down to TodoItemList which renders the TodoItem component and passes the **todos** and **setTodos** down to TodoItem.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import AddItemBar from "./components/AddItemBar";
import TodoItemList from "./components/TodoItemList";
import "./App.css";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

const App = () => {
  // Initial state for todos
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
    { id: uuidv4(), name: "Learn React", complete: false },
    { id: uuidv4(), name: "Graduate from school", complete: false },
    { id: uuidv4(), name: "Get a cool web development job", complete: false },
    { id: uuidv4(), name: "Learn more new technologies", complete: false },
    { id: uuidv4(), name: "Enjoy working life", complete: false }
  ]);

  return (
    <div className="container appbox">
      <TodoItemList todos={todos} setTodos={setTodos} />
      <AddItemBar todos={todos} setTodos={setTodos} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

TodoItemList just loops through the **todos** array and renders a TodoItem for each array item, passing the individual todo, todos array and setTodos function to TodoItem:

```js
import React from "react";
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem";

const TodoItemList = ({ todos, setTodos }) => {
  var items = [];

  // Create todo item list
  todos.forEach(todo => {
    items.push(
      <TodoItem key={todo.id} todo={todo} todos={todos} setTodos={setTodos} />
    );
  });

  return items;
};

export default TodoItemList;
```

TodoItem.js component:

```js
import React from "react";

const TodoItem = ({ todo, todos, setTodos }) => {
  // Todo item color and text changes based on todo.complete state
  var color = todo.complete === true ? "lightgreen" : "bisque";
  var text = todo.complete === true ? "Complete" : "Incomplete";

  // Change completed status for clicked item
  const changeStatus = id => {
    var todoItems = todos.slice();
    for (let i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
      if (todoItems[i].id === id) {
        var newComplete = !todoItems[i].complete;
        todoItems[i].complete = newComplete;
      }
    }

    setTodos(todoItems);
  };

  // Remove todo item
  const deleteItem = id => {
    const newTodos = [...todos];

    var removeIndex = newTodos
      .map(todo => {
        return todo.id;
      })
      .indexOf(id);

    newTodos.splice(removeIndex, 1);

    setTodos(newTodos);
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="row mt-2 mr-1 ml-1 todoItem"
      style={{ backgroundColor: color }}
    >
      <h5 className="col-sm text-center">{todo.name}</h5>
      <button
        className="btn btn-info col-sm-3"
        onClick={() => changeStatus(todo.id)}
      >
        {text}
      </button>
      <button
        className="btn btn-danger col-sm-2"
        onClick={() => deleteItem(todo.id)}
      >
        Delete
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TodoItem;
```

---

Now how do I test the side-effects of these functions in the TodoItem?

Here's the TodoItem.test.js file so far, it only tests the UI (all of them pass), but not the state updates:

```js
import React from "react";
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";

describe("<TodoItem />", () => {
  it("should render without problems", () => {
    const todo = { id: uuidv4(), name: "Learn React", complete: false };
    shallow(<TodoItem todo={todo} />);
  });

  it("shallow wrapper instance should be null", () => {
    const todo = { id: uuidv4(), name: "Learn React", complete: false };
    const wrapper = shallow(<TodoItem todo={todo} />);
    const instance = wrapper.instance();

    expect(instance).toEqual(null);
  });

  it("should have todo text", () => {
    const todo = { id: uuidv4(), name: "Learn React", complete: false };
    const wrapper = shallow(<TodoItem todo={todo} />);
    expect(wrapper.find("h5").length).toEqual(1);
  });

  it("should have a complete button", () => {
    const todo = { id: uuidv4(), name: "Learn React", complete: false };
    const wrapper = shallow(<TodoItem todo={todo} />);
    expect(wrapper.find("button.btn-info").length).toEqual(1);
  });

  it("should have a delete button", () => {
    const todo = { id: uuidv4(), name: "Learn React", complete: false };
    const wrapper = shallow(<TodoItem todo={todo} />);
    expect(wrapper.find("button.btn-danger").length).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

I've read that it would be harmful to test the functions themselves directly,
so I want to just test the side-effects which are:

- **changeStatus**: test if the **todo.complete** changes from **false** to **true**
- **deleteItem**: test if the item is deleted from **todos** array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so after searching Google for a while, I found out that currently it is impossible to test function component's state with Jest/Enzyme.

For example, the `state()` testing function which Enzyme provides is only for class components...